# Calculate power for t-test in Python

Tags: python, scipy, statistics, statsmodels

I have the following R Code, wondering what is the equivalent code in Python

```
power.t.test(n=20,delta=40,sd=50,sig.level=0.05,type= "one.sample",alternative="one.sided")
```

The expected output is:

```
     One-sample t test power calculation 

              n = 20
          delta = 40
             sd = 50
      sig.level = 0.05
          power = 0.9641728
    alternative = one.sided
```

Comment: why isn't there a scipy way of doing this?

Comment: this doesn't give the same answer as this https://stackoverflow.com/a/75215952/1601580 or https://machinelearningmastery.com/statistical-power-and-power-analysis-in-python/ you sure it's right?

Comment: btw, an answer in scipy would be nice.

Answer (score 7):

Found it

```
import statsmodels.stats.power as smp
smp.ttest_power(0.8, nobs=20, alpha=0.05, alternative='larger')
```

Comment: How did you get 0.8 for effect size?

Comment: Effect size is delta/std.

Comment: why isn't there a scipy way of doing this?

Comment: this doesn't give the same answer as this https://stackoverflow.com/a/75215952/1601580 or https://machinelearningmastery.com/statistical-power-and-power-analysis-in-python/ you sure it's right?

Answer (score 2):

Ok this will work:

```
def _compute_power_ttest(effect_size: float, n: int, alpha: float, alternative: str = 'two-sided') -> float:
    """
    Compute power for a t-test from effect size, sample size, alpha, and type of alternative hypothesis.

    Note:
        alternative = 'two-sided' | 'smaller' | 'larger'.

    ref:
        - https://machinelearningmastery.com/statistical-power-and-power-analysis-in-python/
    """
    import statsmodels.stats.power as smp
    power: float = smp.tt_ind_solve_power(effect_size=effect_size, nobs1=n, alpha=alpha, alternative=alternative)
    return power


def get_estimated_number_of_samples_needed_to_reach_certain_power(effect_size: float,
                                                                  power: float,
                                                                  alpha: float,
                                                                  alternative: str = 'two-sided',
                                                                  ) -> float:
    """
    Compute sample size needed to reach a certain power for a t-test. Note the result will be a float.

    Note:
        - Guess: number of observations is the number of observations for RV in question. So if your doing dif = mu1 - mu2
        N estimated or given to power will be the number of difs, not the total from the two groups.

    ref:
        - https://machinelearningmastery.com/statistical-power-and-power-analysis-in-python/
    """
    # perform power analysis
    from statsmodels.stats.power import TTestIndPower
    analysis = TTestIndPower()
    result = analysis.solve_power(effect_size, power=power, nobs1=None, ratio=1.0, alpha=alpha, alternative=alternative)
    return result
```

you can see my ultimate utils for it.

---

Full code:

```
"""
Effect size = is a quantative measure of the strength of a phenomenon. Effect size emphasizes the size of the difference
    or relationship. e.g. the distance between the two means of two hyptoehsis H0, H1 (if they were Gaussian distributions).

Cohen’s d measures the difference between the mean from two Gaussian-distributed variables.
It is a standard score that summarizes the difference in terms of the number of standard deviations.
Because the score is standardized, there is a table for the interpretation of the result, summarized as:
    - Small Effect Size: d=0.20
    - Medium Effect Size: d=0.50
    - Large Effect Size: d=0.80

note:
    - you usually look up the effect size in you application/field (todo why)
    - depends on statistical test/hypothesis decision procedure (e.g. t-test, ANOVA, etc.).
    - large is good if you get a large effect size.
    - Q: why can't we control the effect size? (todo why) I think it's just a function of field/nature & your hypothesis
    - Q: how does it relate to number of samples? does it lead to the issues CIs lead e.g. Pf -> 1 Pm->0?
    - Courtney says, if the effect size is large, then a smaler sample size is needed. My guess is that n (sample size)
    should not affect negatively the effect size.
    - if effect size is small, then a larger sample size is needed (Courney says) (todo: why?)

ref:
    - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9LVD9oLg1A0&list=PLljPCllSdtzWop4iDNyyuZ2NZokOHeQqm&index=6
    - https://machinelearningmastery.com/effect-size-measures-in-python/


todo: later
    Two other popular methods for quantifying the difference effect size are:

    Odds Ratio. Measures the odds of an outcome occurring from one treatment compared to another.
    Relative Risk Ratio. Measures the probabilities of an outcome occurring from one treatment compared to another.
"""


# function to calculate Cohen's d for independent samples
def _cohen_d(d1, d2):
    """
    Compute Cohen's d for independent samples.

    ref:
        - from: https://machinelearningmastery.com/effect-size-measures-in-python/

# seed random number generator
seed(1)
# prepare data
data1 = 10 * randn(10000) + 60
data2 = 10 * randn(10000) + 55
# calculate cohen's d
d = cohend(data1, data2)
print('Cohens d: %.3f' % d)

    Note:
        -   ddof : int, optional
            Means Delta Degrees of Freedom.  The divisor used in calculations
            is ``N - ddof``, where ``N`` represents the number of elements.
            By default `ddof` is zero.
    """
    # calculate the Cohen's d between two samples
    from numpy.random import randn
    from numpy.random import seed
    from numpy import mean
    from numpy import var
    from math import sqrt

    # calculate the size of samples
    n1, n2 = len(d1), len(d2)
    # calculate the variance of the samples
    s1, s2 = var(d1, ddof=1), var(d2, ddof=1)
    # calculate the pooled standard deviation
    s = sqrt(((n1 - 1) * s1 + (n2 - 1) * s2) / (n1 + n2 - 2))
    # calculate the means of the samples
    u1, u2 = mean(d1), mean(d2)
    # calculate the effect size
    cohen_d: float = (u1 - u2) / s
    return cohen_d


def compute_effect_size_t_test_cohens_d(group1: iter, group2: iter) -> tuple[float, float]:
    """
    Compute effect size for a t-test (Cohen's d). The distance in pooled std between the two means.

    Note:
        - The Cohen’s d calculation is not provided in Python; we can calculate it manually. ref: https://machinelearningmastery.com/effect-size-measures-in-python/
        -
    """
    from numpy import mean
    # calculate the pooled standard deviation
    pooled_std: float = compute_pooled_std_two_groups(group1, group2)
    # calculate the means of the samples
    u1, u2 = mean(group1), mean(group2)
    # calculate the effect size
    cohen_d: float = (u1 - u2) / pooled_std
    return cohen_d, pooled_std


def compute_pooled_std_two_groups(group1: iter, group2: iter, ddof: int = 1) -> float:
    """
    Compute pooled std for two groups.

    ref:
        - https://machinelearningmastery.com/effect-size-measures-in-python/
    """
    import numpy as np
    pooled_std: float = np.sqrt((np.std(group1, ddof=ddof) ** 2 + np.std(group2, ddof=ddof) ** 2) / 2)
    return pooled_std


def print_interpretation_of_cohends_d_decision_procedure(d: float):
    """ Print interpretation of Cohen's d decision procedure. """
    print(
        f'Decision: (is a minimal difference between the means of two groups or a minimal relationship between two variables?)')
    d: float = abs(d)
    if d < 0.35:
        print(f"Small Effect Size: d~0.20 {d < 0.35=}")
    elif 0.35 <= d < 0.65:
        print(f"Medium Effect Size: d~0.50 {0.35 <= d < 0.65=}")
    elif d >= 0.65:
        print(f"Large Effect Size: d~0.80 {d >= 0.65=}")
    else:
        raise ValueError(f"Unexpected value for d: {d}")


def decision_based_on_effect_size(d: float, pooled_std: float, eps: float = 0.01):
    """
    Print can't reject null ("accept H1") if the effect size is large enough wrt to eps

    Similar to the CIs test.

    Note:
        - eps - 1% or 2% based on ywx's suggestion (common acceptance for new method is SOTA in CVPR like papers).
    """
    # todo
    d: float = abs(d)
    return d >= eps


# - tests

def my_test_using_stds_from_real_expts_():
    """
    std_maml = std_m ~ 0.061377
    std_usl = std_u ~ 0.085221
    """
    import numpy as np

    # Example data
    std_m = 0.061377
    std_u = 0.085221
    N = 100
    N_m = N
    N_u = N
    mu_m = 0.855
    mu_u = 0.893
    group1 = np.random.normal(mu_m, std_m, N_m)
    group2 = np.random.normal(mu_u, std_u, N_u)
    print(f'{std_m=}')
    print(f'{std_u=}')
    print(f'{N_m=}')
    print(f'{N_u=}')
    print(f'{mu_m=}')
    print(f'{mu_u=}')

    # Perform t-test
    from scipy.stats import ttest_ind
    t_stat, p_value = ttest_ind(group1, group2)

    # Compute Cohen's d
    cohen_d, pooled_std = compute_effect_size_t_test_cohens_d(group1, group2)
    _cohen_d_val: float = _cohen_d(group1, group2)

    print("Cohen's d: ", cohen_d)
    print("_cohen_d: ", _cohen_d_val)
    print_interpretation_of_cohends_d_decision_procedure(cohen_d)

    # Print p-value
    print("p-value: ", p_value)
    alpha: float = 0.01  # significance level
    from uutils.stats_uu.p_values_uu.t_test_uu import print_statistically_significant_decision_procedure
    print_statistically_significant_decision_procedure(p_value, alpha)

    # Print Power P_d (probability of detection, rejecting null if null is false)
    from uutils.stats_uu.power import _compute_power_ttest
    power: float = _compute_power_ttest(cohen_d, N, alpha)
    # from uutils.stats_uu.power import compute_power_posthoc_t_test
    # power2: float = compute_power_posthoc_t_test(cohen_d, N, alpha)
    from uutils.stats_uu.power import _compute_power_ttest
    power2: float = _compute_power_ttest(cohen_d, N, alpha)
    print(f'{power=}')
    print(f'{power2=}')

    # print estimated number samples needed to get power, should be around the N we gave it
    print('---- estimated number samples needed to get power ----')
    print(f'true N used {N=}')
    from uutils.stats_uu.power import get_estimated_number_of_samples_needed_to_reach_certain_power
    N_estimated: float = get_estimated_number_of_samples_needed_to_reach_certain_power(cohen_d, alpha, power)
    print(f'N_estimated {N_estimated=}')
    print('(if gives numerical error ignore)')

# - run it

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import time

    start = time.time()
    # - run it
    my_test_using_stds_from_real_expts_()
    # - Done
    from uutils import report_times

    print(f"\nSuccess Done!: {report_times(start)}\a")
```

output:

```
std_m=0.061377
std_u=0.085221
N_m=100
N_u=100
mu_m=0.855
mu_u=0.893
Cohen's d:  -0.7284714879453533
_cohen_d:  -0.7284714879453533
Decision: (is a minimal difference between the means of two groups or a minimal relationship between two variables?)
Large Effect Size: d~0.80 d >= 0.65=True
p-value:  6.235756440568308e-07
Decision: (Statistically significant?)
H1 (Reject H0, means are statistically different) p_value=6.235756440568308e-07, alpha=0.01, p_value < alpha=True
power=0.9943270164782081
power2=0.9943270164782081
true N used N=100
/Users/brandomiranda/opt/anaconda3/envs/meta_learning/lib/python3.9/site-packages/statsmodels/stats/power.py:415: ConvergenceWarning: 
Failed to converge on a solution.
  warnings.warn(convergence_doc, ConvergenceWarning)
import sys; print('Python %s on %s' % (sys.version, sys.platform))
N_estimated N_estimated=array([10.])
Success Done!: time passed: hours:0.0020856397019492256, minutes=0.12513838211695352, seconds=7.508302927017212
```

Answer (score -1):

The equivalent code in Python would be using the scipy library's ttest_1samp method:

```
from scipy import stats

stats.ttest_1samp(a=40, popmean=20, axis=None, ddof=0, nan_policy='propagate')
```